# AS3 - SharedObject over https

Tags: actionscript-3, https, shared-objects

Is it safe to store a password in a SharedObject if it gets saved over https from a Flash based webapp?
I'm not sure if I get the [Adobe reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) right on this.

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a local SharedObject, it's local to the computer, so it's as safe as sharing a cookie. (Probably still want to encrypt to prevent against session jacking.)

If you're using a remote SharedObject, connecting over HTTPS would encrypt it during transfer which sounds pretty safe. You would probably still want to encrypt it within the SharedObject because storing a plain text password *anywhere* is a bad idea.